# Jenkinsfile with writeFile inside docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

If I have a Jenkinsfile with

```
docker.image('foo').inside {
    writeFile file: bar, text: baz
}
```

the file gets written to the Jenkins agent's workspace, not inside the container, right? Is there a sane way to write a file inside a container?

The closest thing I was able to find on the web is https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33510. I suppose I could use a `sh` step with a here-doc, but that sounds pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workspace in the container and you can write files inside the container with `writeFiles`.
But it's also shared with the workspace of the host node because it's mounted as a volume.

> `inside` will:
>
> 1. Automatically grab a slave and a workspace (no extra node block is
>      required).
> 2. Pull the requested image to the Docker server (if not already cached).
> 3. Start a container running that image.
> 4. Mount the Jenkins workspace as a “volume” inside the container, using
>      the same file path.

You can see more detail what happens in `inside` here: https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/chapter-docker-workflow.html